# A question on surface integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, surfaces

The glass dome of a futuristic greenhouse is shaped like the surface
$$
z = 8 - 2 x^{2} - 2 y^{2}.
$$
The greenhouse has a flat dirt floor at $ z = 0 $. Suppose that the temperature $ T $, at points $ (x,y,z) $ in and around the greenhouse, varies as
$$
T(x,y,z) = x^{2} + y^{2} + 3 (z - 2)^{2}.
$$
Then the temperature gives rise to a **heat flux density field $ H $** given by $ H = - k \nabla(T) $.

Find the total heat flux outward across the dome and the surface of the ground if $ k = 1 $ on the glass and $ k = 3 $ on the ground.

---

I know that I need to find the surface integral across the region $ z = 0 $ and across the paraboloid $ z = 8 - 2 x^{2} - 2 y^{2} $ to find the flux, but I’m not sure whether it’s
$$
\iint_{S} T ~ \mathrm{d}{\Sigma}
$$
or
$$
\iint_{S} H ~ \mathrm{d}{\Sigma}
$$
that I need to do. Also, how do I parametrize $ T $ (or $ H $) to find the surface integral?

Any help would be really appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: It's $H$ ($T$ is not even a vector field). The greenhouse is a stretched sphere, so you could use spherical coordinates. However, it might be easier to use Gauss's theorem to turn it into a volume integral.

Comment: Got it! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, it's a parabola not a sphere.

Comment: Coming in late, not sure if Gauss's theorem is the best approach. You'd have the total flux across the volume, but you want each flux separately. Moreover, the factor $k$ is different for each surface. I think it's best to compute each the usual way.